# How can I make sure my portable toolbox hasn't got any tools missing?

Tags: tools

**Background**

I have a big house and I've managed to have tools scattered across the house (basement shop, kitchen, garage (bike tools). I can't, at this time, consolidate them all in one place (no room to work in one place for the 7 bikes *and* room to work on other projects).

**Goal**

I'd like to just put most of the important tools in my toolbox (actually a tool "bag"). But... I miss the benefit of having a nice pegboard with outlines for all tools so I know if a tool is missing.

Any suggestions of a better toolbag/box that addresses this or perhaps some method?
(I've currently labelled (yes, I'm that anal retentive ;-) pockets in the bag for important tools but I still have to visually inspect them. Invevitably, I'm in the middle of something and find I'm missing a tool (sometimes purloined by my kids)

Comment: [here's](http://woodgears.ca/tool_holders/zimmerman.html) a set of himemade tool chests that has spots for everything

Comment: Tag all the tools with [RFID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification) tags, then use a scanner to determine which tools are present/missing. This might be an expensive, over elaborate solution.

Comment: Sign up all the tools for Facebook, and give them smartphones. Then they can check in to the toolbox and annoy the heck out of all of their friends with superfluous updates on their whereabouts.

Comment: @Doresoom - Genius!

Comment: @Tester101, your RFID suggestion is actually catching on in the aviation maintenance industry, where leaving a $5 tool on aircraft can cause $1000's in serious damage.

Comment: @Doresoom The medical industry uses bar codes.  During surgery (or any time you're in the hospital really) before any tool or supply is used, the bar code is scanned.  After the surgery everything has to be scanned again, to make sure it's not in the patient's body.

Answer (score 11):

A simple method may be just to weigh the toolbag when it has a complete set of tools.  Record the number.  Whenever you need the toolbag, quickly weigh it again.  If the number matches then everything is accounted for.  If not, then you would need to rummage through and see what is missing.